# jQuery toggling the checked property on a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to check or uncheck a buttonstyled checkbox with the following code:

```
<ul id="ids_ul" class="nav nav-list">
    <li>
        <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-info group_toggle" id="id_label1" for="id_checkboxes1">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="id_checkboxes1" name="ids[]" autocomplete="off"/> One</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-success group_toggle" id="id_label2" for="id_checkboxes2">
            <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="id_checkboxes2" name="ids[]" autocomplete="off"/> Two</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-info group_toggle" id="id_label3" for="id_checkboxes3">
            <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="id_checkboxes3" name="ids[]" autocomplete="off"/> Three</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

let checkbox_state = "";
$(".group_toggle").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-info btn-success");
    checkbox_state = $(this).children("input:first");

    console.log("Initial checkbox_state: " + checkbox_state.prop("checked"));
    if($(checkbox_state).prop("checked") == true) {
        $(checkbox_state).prop("checked", false);
        console.log("Checked after click: " + checkbox_state.prop("checked"));
    } else {
        $(checkbox_state).prop("checked", true);
        console.log("Checked after click: " + checkbox_state.prop("checked"));
    }
});
```

After four clicks on `Two` the log shows:

```
Initial checkbox_state: true
Checked after click: false

Initial checkbox_state: true // why still true?
Checked after click: false

Initial checkbox_state: false
Checked after click: true

Initial checkbox_state: true
Checked after click: false
```

On the 3rd click the uncheck works, but the button-class is now the opposite.
If i click on `One` or `Three` to check the checkbox it works in the first try.

Does someone know what happens here?

Is there a more elegant way to verify the checkbox property `checked`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the default behavior of the clicked element, which seemed to cause the click event to fire twice when using twitter-bootstrap-3

Also, `checkbox_state` seems like a confusing name for the element, being as it actually stores the checkbox itself and you use `prop('checked')` to get it's state - I've updated this and change it to be inside the function, as you  did not need this to be globally defined

```js
$('.group_toggle').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).toggleClass('btn-info btn-success');

  let $checkbox = $(this).children('input:first');
  let checked = $checkbox.prop('checked');

  console.log(`Initial checkbox_state: ${checked}`);
  
  // Invert checked state
  $checkbox.prop('checked', !checked);
  console.log(`Checked after click: ${$checkbox.prop('checked')}`);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="ids_ul" class="nav nav-list">
  <li>
    <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-info group_toggle" id="id_label1" for="id_checkboxes1">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="id_checkboxes1" name="ids[]" autocomplete="off"/>One
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-success group_toggle" id="id_label2" for="id_checkboxes2">
        <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="id_checkboxes2" name="ids[]" autocomplete="off"/>Two
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-info group_toggle" id="id_label3" for="id_checkboxes3">
        <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="id_checkboxes3" name="ids[]" autocomplete="off"/>Three
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note sure that if its it related to Bootstrap, as I reproduced the double click event in a snippet with jQuery and no Bootstrap lib. Maybe due to jQuery `data-toggle attribute`. I could not figure out what causes the double event.

Comment: You can simplify the toggle to `$checkbox.prop('checked', !checked)`. It will automatically set its value to the opposite of the current value that way. No `if...else` required.

Comment: In the snippet it works pretty well, but not for me. I think i overwrite somewhere the property so i'll have to search for it. Anyways. Thank you for the solution and @NathanMiller for this short sweet code.

Comment: I'll make the changes Nathan suggested - thank you for pointing that out; glad you found your solution @GePu

Answer (score 0):

To somewhat expand on @Light's answer

The problem that I can see is the order of events happening and you trying to manually control the state of a checkbox. When you wrap a checkbox with a label (or use the for="#id" on the label) it delegates a click to the checkbox whenever the label is clicked (which is why it gets triggered twice). The other thing is your initial state of the buttons was incorrect, button Two had the class btn-success but was not active and the related checkbox wasn't checked. See below for complete resolution

```js
let checkbox_state = "";
$(".group_toggle").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   $(this).toggleClass("btn-info btn-success");
    checkbox_state = $(this).children("input:first");

    console.log("Initial checkbox_state: " + checkbox_state.prop("checked"));
    if($(checkbox_state).prop("checked") == true) {
        checkbox_state.prop('checked', false);
        console.log("Checked after click: " + checkbox_state.prop("checked"));
    } else {
        checkbox_state.prop('checked', true);
        console.log("Checked after click: " + checkbox_state.prop("checked"));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="ids_ul" class="nav">
    <li>
        <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-info group_toggle" id="id_label1" for="id_checkboxes1">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="id_checkboxes1" name="ids[]" autocomplete="off"/> One</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-success group_toggle active" id="id_label2" for="id_checkboxes2">
            <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="id_checkboxes2" name="ids[]" autocomplete="off" checked=""/> Two</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-info group_toggle" id="id_label3" for="id_checkboxes3">
            <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="id_checkboxes3" name="ids[]" autocomplete="off"/> Three</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```